# Python3 requests, cookie is set but still 401 unauthorized

Tags: python-3.x, rest, cookies, python-requests

I can access a website, through Firefox, which requires authentication. I know precisely the cookie that is associated with the session by deleting every other cookie.

I need to send REST Get requests from a python script to this website. I'm setting the cookie like so:

```
import requests

header = dict(PHPSESSID='cookie...')

resp = requests.get("http://website/with/rest/api?arguments...", cookies=header)

print(resp)
print(resp.text)
```

But the answer is always

```
<Response [401]>
Not Authorized
```

What mechanism could be preventing me from accessing the site from a script? I'm not aware of anything else than cookies to identify myself.

Comment: Check the rest documentation of the website. With no more information, we cannot help you.  Some sites requires authorization/registration before to be able to access the rest api. Possibly you are missing such initial step.

Comment: My question is mainly, what is the difference between a GET that I can see in the Firefox developer console, and a GET in a python script? If I set up the exact same parameters and cookies, shouldn't there be no differences?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is the difference if you don't show us the URL. Maybe the server looks at the user agent, maybe some other header. Who knows?

Comment: Actually that was it, I needed to add the user agent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trick the website so it thinks you are using a browser.

For this, use a header like this one `trick_header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}` and call `requests.get("http://website/with/rest/api?arguments...", cookies=header, headers=trick_header)`